ADB QR: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
In VS code ADB QR: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
i want to connect my android device to vs code
i m ana beginner and have no background knowledge and understanding of coding.
let me know is there is a better alternative to adb qr to connect android device and work on building my own app
installed adb qr in vs code extensions

Did you install android platform tools on your machine?

yes i did install android studio

I did not mean Android Studio. I meant android platform tools. Those are two different things.


Verify adb Installation
First, ensure that adb is indeed installed. You can check this by opening a Command Prompt or Terminal window and typing:
adb version


Add adb to System PATH
If adb is installed but not recognized, you likely need to add its location to your system's PATH environment variable. Here’s how to do it on Windows:
-- Find the adb Path: The typical path for adb within the Android SDK is
something like C:\Users<YourUsername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools.Replace  with your actual username.
-- Add to PATH: Open
the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system
environment variables” (or search for “Environment Variables”).
-- Click the “Environment Variables…” button.
-- Under “System Variables”, scroll down and select the “Path” variable, then click “Edit…”.
-- In the Edit Environment Variable window, click “New” and paste the path to the adb directory.
-- Click OK on all windows to apply the changes.
After adding adb to your PATH, open a new Command Prompt or Terminal window
and try running adb version again to verify it's accessible.


. Connect Your Device
adb devices


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
